# How to expose a property in MBean description

Tags: java, spring, properties, jmx, spring-jmx

The following managed operation exists in the project:

```
@ManagedOperation(description = "Some description")
@ManagedOperationParameters({
        @ManagedOperationParameter(name = "key", description = "Some description"),
})
public void foo(String key) {
    // some logic
}
```

Also there is a property which can be used in Spring context by surrounding it with dollar sign and square brackets:

```
"${some.property.key}"
```

Is it possible to use the value of aforementioned property key in the managed operation annotation description? Something like:

```
@ManagedOperationParameter(name = "key", 
    description = "Some description, please note that the key is ${some.property.key}")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not out-of-the-box, but it's pretty easy to customize...

```
public class CustomAttributeSource extends AnnotationJmxAttributeSource implements EmbeddedValueResolverAware {

    private StringValueResolver embeddedValueResolver;

    @Override
    public void setEmbeddedValueResolver(StringValueResolver resolver) {
        this.embeddedValueResolver = resolver;
    }

    @Override
    public ManagedAttribute getManagedAttribute(Method method) throws InvalidMetadataException {
        ManagedAttribute managedAttribute = super.getManagedAttribute(method);
        if (this.embeddedValueResolver != null) {
            managedAttribute
                    .setDescription(this.embeddedValueResolver.resolveStringValue(managedAttribute.getDescription()));
        }
        return managedAttribute;
    }

    @Override
    public ManagedOperation getManagedOperation(Method method) throws InvalidMetadataException {
        ManagedOperation managedOperation = super.getManagedOperation(method);
        if (this.embeddedValueResolver != null) {
            managedOperation
                    .setDescription(this.embeddedValueResolver.resolveStringValue(managedOperation.getDescription()));
        }
        return managedOperation;
    }

}
```

Then...

```
<bean class="org.springframework.jmx.export.annotation.AnnotationMBeanExporter">
    <property name="assembler">
        <bean class="org.springframework.jmx.export.assembler.MetadataMBeanInfoAssembler">
            <property name="attributeSource">
                <bean class="foo.CustomAttributeSource" />
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```